# UITableViewCell image update in one cell automatically/annoyingly gets to other cells too

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Am a newbie to iOS programming (but I've done my homework ... going through books on iOS and google tutorials). Am trying to do this:

1. User inputs some text in a text field, & chooses an emoticon.
2. I then add the user-input-text to a UITableViewCell and add the cell to the UITableView.

**The Problem :**

> Say, the user enters some text and chooses the 'happy' emoticon.
>
> The emoticon and text get updated in the UITableView. No problem with this.
>
> Next, the user enters some other text, and chooses the 'sad' emoticon.
>
> The problem is:
> The emoticon in the previous cell (where it's a happy emoticon) also changes to 'sad'; but I  don't want the previous cell changes.

```
@synthesize table;
@synthesize buttonEmotionHappy;
@synthesize buttonEmotionLaugh;

int myEmoticonNum;

/**
 * Called when the button's pressed
 * sender : the button which's pressed, consequently invoking this
 */
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    [self addToInputArray:[textFieldUserInput text]];

    [table reloadData];
    textFieldUserInput.text = @"";
}


-(IBAction)emotionExpressed:(id)sender {

    if (sender == buttonEmotionHappy) {
    
        NSLog(@"Happy emoticon chosen");
        myEmoticonNum = 1;
    
    } else if (sender == buttonEmotionSad) {
    
        NSLog(@"Sad emoticon chosen");
        myEmoticonNum = 2;
    }
}

...
...
...
...
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.arrayInput count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
    
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
            reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    if (myEmotionNum == 1) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SmileyHappy.png"];

    } else if (myEmotionNum == 2) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SmileySad.png"];
    }  


    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayInput objectAtIndex:row];
    
    return cell;
}

-(void) addToInputArray: (NSString *)userInput {

    [arrayInput insertObject:userInput atIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Added %@ to User-Input-Array", userInput);
}
```

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: could you post the datasource method cellForRowAtIndexPath:?  Usually this kind of problem is caused by not dealing correctly with the tableView's reuse of cells.  i.e. if you dequeue a cell, it's one you've configured already and it might contain remnants (i.e. like an emoticon) from a prior config.

Comment: Hi Danh, Thanks for your reply. I have posted the cellForRowAtIndexPath method in my original post. Now, I have changed the logic (and the post too) that it now uses an int to save the emoticon the user has chosen. However, the issue persists. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing a single value `myEmotionNum` which means every cell will get the same emoticon. You need to store one emotion per row/cell.

You could set up a parallel array (like `self.arrayEmotions`) for the emotion IDs or use a single array and store dictionaries. In JSON format, I'm suggesting something like:

```
[ { "text": "Hello", "emotion": 1 },
  { "text": "Next row", "emotion": 2} ]
```

So your `addToInputArray:` would look like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  userInput, @"text", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"emotion"];
[arrayInput insertObject:dict atIndex:0];
```

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you would get the text out like:

```
[[arrayInput objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"text"]
```

And the emotion # out like:

```
[[[arrayInput objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"emotion"] intValue]
```

And you could set the emotion # like:

```
[[arrayInput objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someEmoticonNumber] forKey:@"emotion"]
```

(Note that dictionaries have to store objects, which is why you need to convert to/from `NSNumber`)

Comment: This is a good example of how to code it.  Agree with @Jenox and +1 here, also.  Let us know if you need further help.  The concept is that an array of objects usually represents the datasource for a table.  The cellForRow method is where you render a particular row of the table with *a particular row* of the datasource.  To change the table, change the contents of the array, then let your table know it needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks so much, gregheo! Awesome! It works now! :-) & thanks, danh! :-) I wasn't aware that it needs an array; I have to remember that UITableViewCell doesn't function like any usual Table object in other programming languages. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the `imageEmotion` per cell, not per table view.
Try to add it as a property to your custom cell class.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion. In the method "-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath", I added "UIImage *image = imageEmotion;", but the issue persists.

Comment: @Jenox has got it right.  Anything you want to be different on a per cell basis needs to be in an array.